# How to configure git autocrlf=true on tfs build server

Tags: git, tfs, tfsbuild

I will use autocrlf=true on my tfs build server. My first try was to set a .gitconfig in the user folder of the tfs build controller user. It worked for 2 days :(. Now we have the same problem. All checkout's in the build process have unix line endings on the build server. How can I configure that? The tfs git setup has no .gitconfig or something else.

Comment: A new installed and configured tfs build controller checks everything out with unix line-endings. I see now why to configure autocrlf=true because tfs ignores the global git config.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out what's going on here. We played with some configs in the .gitattribute. Now the problem was that the tfs clone the master first and switch to the queued branch on every build. So that Git will use the attributes from the master branch. We didn't merge the attributes in the master branch :(. That was the problem.